# ajax call does not make it to success function

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, url, xml-parsing

I have an issue where I am simply trying to make an ajax call to an xml file that is in the parent folder of my js file. I was led to believe the issue was my URL.

When the url was "../a2.xml" I would get an error of being unable to load resource. I then changed it to "a2.xml" and this does not give me that same error yet the call still does not reach the success function.

jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(event)
{
   console.log("Before ajax call.");
   $.ajax
   ({
      url:'a2.xml',
      type:'GET',
      dataType:'xml',
      success: function(data)
      {
          console.log("Success");
          //var varxmldoc = data
          //var name = $(xmldoc).find('studentName').text();
          //body = '<h1>'+name+'</h1><hr>';

          //$(body).appendTo('div');
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: You should check your browser's *Network* console and / or add an `error` callback to see what's going wrong

Comment: Ajax path has no relevance to where your js file comes from...it is always relative to the page you load the script in.

Comment: The error was "Error: Invalid XML: <?xml version="1.0"?>
(…)"

Comment: Run the xml through a validator

Comment: GOD I'M F**KING RETARDED. Thank you very much sir/madam.